# Will reference to member variable get corrupted after object deletion?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can I use `ref` after object deletion like shown in this example or is it unsafe?

```
struct Object
{
    int value;
};

void function()
{
    Object* object = new Object();
    int& ref = object->value;
    delete object;
    ref = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unsafe.

Any use of a pointer or reference to a member of a destroyed object is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot. `Object::value` is a subobject of `Object`.  Destroying `*object` also destroys `object->value`.  After `delete object;`, the reference no longer refers to a valid object and any usage of the value of `ref` is undefined behavior.